# PayFort IOS SDK gives crash when initialized

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, payfort

I am trying to implement PayFort in my IOS Mobile application
    I have added PayFort FrameWork and bundle in project. When i Initialize payFort object it gives me following crash

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField setFloatingLabelActiveTextColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f81e3413d40'

I am using following piece of code:

```
     func  payforCall(){
        let payFort = PayFortController.init(enviroment: KPayFortEnviromentSandBox)
        payFort?.isShowResponsePage = true;
        payFort?.delegate=self
        let request = NSMutableDictionary.init()
        request.setValue("1000", forKey: "amount")
        request.setValue("AUTHORIZATION", forKey: "command")
        request.setValue("USD", forKey: "currency")
        request.setValue("email@domain.com", forKey: "customer_email")
        request.setValue("en", forKey: "language")
        request.setValue("112233682686", forKey: "merchant_reference")
        request.setValue("token" , forKey: "sdk_token")

        payFort?.callPayFort(withRequest: request, currentViewController: self,
                            success: { (requestDic, responeDic) in
                                print("success")
        },
                            canceled: { (requestDic, responeDic) in
                                print("canceled")
        },
                            faild: { (requestDic, responeDic, message) in
                                print("faild")

        })
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Set -ObjC in the Other Linker Flags in the Target -> Build Settings Tab

Comment: have you seen Tags on Question? i am pretty sure if you have scene you haven't given this kind of answer.

Comment: Yes. I came across the same issue. But I had made this amendment and this issue error was resolved.
Rather than this I can see : request.setValue("token" , forKey: "sdk_token")
In this statement there is no device token.

Comment: it was only due to missingness of some Classes. That contained definition of setFloatingLabelActiveTextColor method

Comment: Ok then help me in getting the sdk_token for sandbox account. How can I get that?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I spent couple of hours working on it before realize I typed -objc with small "C" letter 
[image: check this image to see..]

In project build settings -> `Other Linker Flags` -> Set to `-ObjC`